# Как сделать распознавание цифр?

Tags: java, распознавание-символов

Здраствуйте! Так уж случилось что я разработчик-новичок андроид и делаю небольшой проект-приложение на смартфон, где требуется функция распознавания цифр примерно таких как на фото. Как я это могу реализовать, какие библиотеки использовать, какие шаги чтобы это сделать?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Уточните как нужно проводить распознавание - можно сначала вручную выбрать распознаваемую область или прога должна сама определить область для распознавания?

Comment: @Barmaley, сначала вручную выбрать область которую будет распознавать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На гитхабе целый зоопарк таких разработок. Вот [ссылка с поиском](https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=android%20ocr&type=).

[Здесь](https://github.com/GautamGupta/Simple-Android-OCR) одно из самых простых решений и [отдельно его код](https://github.com/GautamGupta/Simple-Android-OCR/blob/master/src/com/datumdroid/android/ocr/simple/SimpleAndroidOCRActivity.java).

Но я думаю, что вам может понадобиться более сложное решение, раз вы собираетесь определять данные со счетчиков.

Также пригодятся статьи точно относящиеся к вашей теме, начните с этого:

[Съёмка показаний счетчика на телефон с последующим распознаванием](https://habrahabr.ru/post/220869/)

А от себя посоветую не брать сразу фотографию с кучей элементов для определения. Сделайте тестовые варианты, вырежьте отдельные числа (прямо с квадратами, в которых они находятся) и тренируйтесь определять сначала их, а когда начнет получаться - расширяйте тестовые варианты до полных фото.