# Нейросеть с анализом объектов

Tags: python, neuralbase

Начал изучать нейросети, взялся за один интересный, по моему мнению проект, но не знаю с чего начать.
Суть проекта:
Необходимо написать код, который будет анализировать изображение, которое показывает пользователь программе. Изображение содержит 39 предохранителей. Нужно обнаружить предохранители на плате предохранителей, извлечь каждый предохранитель в качестве подизображения из основного изображения один за другим, распознавая цифры и буквы на них.
Подскажите пожалуйста, какие нейросетевые библиотеки наиболее подойдут для данного функционала ?
Спасибо.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Вообще-то у вас тут три задачи -  распознать изображение, распознать цифры и придумать, где вы возьмете пару тысяч разных фото с вашими переключателями для обучения нейронной сети.
По первой задаче - могу подсказать, например, ознакомиться с

https://www.asozykin.ru/deep_learning/2018/07/24/Object-Detection-using-TensorFlow.html

https://www.intuit.ru/studies/courses/10621/1105/lecture/17983?page=4

http://ai-news.ru/2018/11/alexnet_svertochnaya_nejroset_dlya_klassifikacii_izobrazhenij.html

По второму -

[Как сделать распознавание цифр?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/797210/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%80)

Вот по  третьему ничего подсказать не могу, думать вам.

Но думаю, прежде, чем браться за реализацию, стоит все-таки потратить время на изучение азов нейросетей. И тогда, возможно, для распознавания тех-же букв (с довольно строгими начертанием, размещением, контрасностью) вам не захочется городить огород с нейросетью, а ограничитесь классическими методами OSR.